# How to test Ktor server always with a raw server setup?

Tags: kotlin, testing, server, client, ktor

Let's say I need to test my API made with ktor, like following:

```kotlin
import kotlin.test.Test


class MyTests {

  @Test
  fun testGet() {
    //...
  }

  @Test
  fun testPost() {
    //...
  }

  @Test
  fun testPut() {
    //...
  }

  @Test
  fun testDelete() {
    //...
  }
}
```

Im'm trying to consider the each tests as something isolated and independent from each other. In this case, each test should have its own setup from scratch, for example:

```kotlin
  @Test
  fun testPost() = testSuspend {
    val testServer = TestApplicationEngine(createTestEnvironment {
      developmentMode = false
      module {
        configureRouting()
        configureSerialization()
      }
    })

    val testClient = testServer.client.config {
      install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
      }
    }
    testServer.start(wait = false)

    val targetCredentials = Credentials("myName", "123")
    val postResponse = testClient.post("/api/users") {
      contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
      setBody(targetCredentials)
    }
    val uuid = postResponse.body<String>()

    val getUserResponse = testClient.get("/api/users/${uuid}")
    val receivedUser = getUserResponse.body<User>()

    assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, getUserResponse.status)
    assertEquals(targetCredentials.username, receivedUser.credentials!!.username)

    testServer.stop()
    testServer.cancel()
    testClient.cancel()
  }
```

This is extremely weird but I didn't got the tests working individually even creating the variables locally and manually like that.

I'm currently testing this by using as database a local static list of users, I know is a bad practice in some concepts, but I was studying the ktor structure. For visualization, think my root data source is:

```kotlin
private val users = mutableListOf<User>()
```

I think that always a new `@Test` begins even I previously programmatically "shut down" the server/client in the end of the other `@Test`, for some reason the local user list data keeps alive, the server seems not being fully disposed or something like that. For example, running the above test and the test below at same run, the can not be created because it already exists:

```kotlin
@Test
fun testGetUser() = testSuspend {
        val testServer = TestApplicationEngine(createTestEnvironment {
          developmentMode = false
          module {
            configureRouting()
            configureSerialization()
          }
        })

        val testClient = testServer.client.config {
          install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
          }
        }

        testServer.start(wait = false)

        val targetCredentials = Credentials("myName", "123")

        val postResponse = testClient.post("/api/users") {
          contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
          setBody(targetCredentials)
        }

        val uuid = postResponse.body<String>()

        val getUserResponse = testClient.get("/api/users/${uuid}")

        val receivedUser = getUserResponse.body<User>()

        assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, getUserResponse.status)
        assertEquals(targetCredentials.username, receivedUser.credentials!!.username)

        testServer.stop()
        testServer.cancel()
        testClient.cancel()
}
```

How the best way to deal with that individual tests?

EDIT:
Tried to move those initial server/client setup to a fixed function and annotate it with `@BeforeTest` and finish/close server to a function annotated with `@AfterTest` but even doing this seems that the server system still in memory.

This is supposed to happen? The server shouldn't be killed each on `@AfterTest` and restarted from scratch before each test?

Comment: What kind of database do you use? How and where do you truncate data from the database?

Comment: Currently I'm setting up my database as a basic Kotlin List. I was using this only to study the project structure but when tried to test that problems appeared.

Comment: In this case, think my database as `private val users = mutableListOf<User>()`

Comment: Why can't you use the `testApplication` function for testing? Can you please share two self-contained tests which conflict with each other?